# Bundle is waiting for namespace handlers blueprint and cxf

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix

I'm having problems re-deployin a JAR on Servicemix (5.5.1) using Blueprint, Camel and Camel-CXF:

```
org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.3 | Bundle my-camel-project is waiting  
for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf, 
http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint]
```

Aparently, certains URLs has been modified today:

- http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf -> Not found
- http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint -> Index of /schema/blueprint

This is a part of my blueprint definition:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"
  xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
  xmlns:camelcxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd">
  ...
  <camelcxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceSoap"
    address="http://localhost:8989/soap" serviceClass="my.path.ServiceSOAP" />
  ...
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    ...
  </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

I builded this codes following a lot of examples on Camel tutorials and Camel In Action book. Was working some days, but not right now.

There are something new recently?

Comment: When you say "re-deploying" you mean the initial deployment of your bundle works but it does not start when un-deployed and then deployed again?

Comment: I'm create an new simple project, just for test, with the blueprint code founded on: http://camel.apache.org/using-osgi-blueprint-with-camel.html.

Over a new uncompresed folder of servicemix and the log say:

INFO  | x-5.5.1/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.3 | Bundle pad-camel-cxf-stackoverflow is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint]

Comment: And you have installed the `camel-cxf` feature?

Comment: Yes, aparently features camel-cxf and cxf are installed by default (feaures:list | grep cxf). The problem was on my POM file, specificaly on maven-bundle-plugin: <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile</Embed-Dependency>. Removing this instruction all work fine again.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if you answer your own question, it's a good idea to write it as an answer, not a comment... :-)